# R - TBATS Function - how to specify nested seasonality?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

One of the main advantages of the TBATS model is that it can detect and work with multiple seasonality - e.g. nested seasonality.

I have a time series which has two nested seasonal cycles - an intra-year weekly cycle (Week 48, Week 49 etc), and an intra-week daily cycle (Sunday, Monday, etc).

I have used the tbats function to forecast this series, and viewed the output.  Initially, I left the seasonal periods as "NULL" (meaning auto-detect), and this generated a simple straight line, having captured none of the seasonality in the model.  However, I changed the time periods to 365, and this then generated a series of forecasts which did correspond reasonably well to the intra-year weekly variation, but with little daily variation.  I think this means that while the function is not (in this case) able to detect the seasonality in the model, once "told" the seasonality, it does a good job of forecasting with it.  I would therefore like to "tell" the model that the seasonality is nested, but I don't know how/if you can do this.  I have tried:

```
 x<-tbats(y,seasonal.periods={365,7})
```

but this doesn't work, and generates an error.

Comment: seasonal.periods=c(365,7)

Comment: Thanks, Professor.